# The requested resource does not support http method 'GET' in DELETE method of 2sxc

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

When I try to delete an item in a 2sxc (11.7.3) app on DNN 9.5.0 I get a 405 error.
On /api/2sxc/cms/list/delete?index=5&parent=&fields=
It says:
{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}

So is this something I must enable in 2sxc somewhere?
Or is it something else?

Comment: Your url says delete but your Http Method is GET.
It should probably be DELETE. From where you send this request?

Comment: Yes, that might be the issue, but then it would be a bug in 2sxc.
I know in the older versions it used to send a DELETE but now it sends a GET.
Perhaps @iJungleBoy knows...

Comment: Message is pretty clear. There is no HttpGet on that Url...

Comment: Unless I should enable it somewhere in 2sxc configuration.